# Runtime error: Can't start new thread - But not multithreading python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

So I am trying to run quite a large program on a large instance in AWS. This program is looping through 44 different tables, all in csv's,  and comparing each table against every other table. To do this, the program is essentially calculating all possible permutation combinations of each table's column against the other table's column, up to the size of 3, and doing some analysis on how closely the data is correlated when the said combination of columns are used to link the two tables to do this. I am mostly using pandas to accomplish this.

I have paralyzed the program such that I have a pool of processes for each table comparison, ie, table A against B, A -> C, A -> D, then B->C, B->D, and so forth. This comes out to a pool of about 1400.

All of this works perfectly fine, but usually, around my 300th process, I get an error about cant start a new thread and it states I have 500+- threads. My confusion comes in the fact I am not multi-threading, so why do I have so many threads? Furthermore, I even tried limiting the pool to only have 10 concurrent processes. I am confused how only 10 processes are somehow using 500 threads when I am not even creating threads.

I am sure this is just a lack of my understanding of how python works, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here you can see my paralization

```
pool = mp.Pool(10) 
for filename in os.listdir("inputFiles"):
    for subFileName in  os.listdir("inputFiles"):
        if subFileName != filename and (str(subFileName + filename) not in ComparedTables):
            
            ComparedTables.append(str(filename + subFileName))
            TABLEA = filename.split(".")[0]
            TABLEB = subFileName.split(".")[0]
            
            print("Creating pocess for: " + TABLEA + " -> " + TABLEB)
            total.append(1)
            pool.apply_async(Paralizer, args=(TABLEA, TABLEB, DataMap,doneCount,total,))              


pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable, honestly. Is it possible that the "Paralizer" function is doing something multithreaded? Can you paste the error message you're getting?

Comment: The paralyzer function is very CPU and it is making lots of comparisons, but I'm not explicitly multi-threading anything. Is there anything in python that automatically multi-threads? Like, do certain functions execute on multithreaded, or do open files exist on a serparate thread?

Comment: There is a hard maximum number of processes (generally quite a large number), but amazon may have artificially limited this. The practical limit is more often related to how much ram you have. perhaps set a `maxtasksperchild` on your `pool` to try and clean up any resources that aren't managed properly. There do exist things in python that aren't perfectly memory managed... if the process quits, the OS should be able to clean up..

Comment: perhaps even too many file handles open. `ulimit -n` should tell you the maximum number of file handles (for any given shell). This actually seems most likely to me... something not closing file handles properly while you're walking directories. fix is the same (maxtasksperchild) unless you find out where the files aren't being closed.

Comment: As an aside, you can dispense with the `ComapredTables` list (it should have been a set for efficiency) and just use `for filename, subFileName in itertools.combinations(os.listdir('inputFiles'), 2):` to get all pairs of files in directory `inputFiles`.